# Access test events parameter in lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

Test events parameter in aws lambda console has been saved as dict in `configure test events`:

```
{"key1":5,
 "name1":"stud1",
 "key2":3,
 "name2":"stud2"}
```

This is accessed as event['key1'] or event['name1'] in lambda function. When tested using console, it seems to run fine. But when scheduled using cloudwatch, the function logs throws a `key error` with event['']. How to access test event parameters with cloudwatch

Answer (score 1):

The "Test events" capability is purely a function of the Lambda console.

When calling a function in any other way, the Lambda function will receive a "real" event.

For an AWS Lambda function triggered by an **Amazon CloudWatch schedule**, CloudWatch will provide an event like this:

```json
{
  "id": "cdc73f9d-aea9-11e3-9d5a-835b769c0d9c",
  "detail-type": "Scheduled Event",
  "source": "aws.events",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "region": "ap-southeast-2",
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:events:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:rule/ExampleRule"
  ],
  "detail": {}
}
```

When configuring the **Target** in the CloudWatch Events rule, it is possible to pass additional information into the event, such as a constant that can then be used by the Lambda function.

**Bottom line:** A Test Event is just for testing in the console.